# I want to close the website if the user answers yes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a joke website and I want to be able to close or exit the website if the user answers yes to being a basket case.....

```
var basket = prompt("are you a basket case?");
var vegtables = prompt("How many times do you eat vegtables at least  once a day in a week?");
if (basket === "yes")
{
window.close();
}

if (parseInt(workOut) >= 5) {
alert("Good job! Keep it up")
}
else {
alert("Looks like there is room for improvement, visit my fitness page")
}

if (parseInt(vegtables) >= 6) {
("Good job! keep it up!")
}
else {
alert("You need to eat more vegtables, visit my health and reboot pages!")
 }
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: that didn't work I tried it....that was a good link though

Comment: It won't close if you say yes

Comment: Google "javascript close window".

Comment: By the way, putting a function declaration inside the `if` block won't accomplish anything at all.

Comment: I want the window to close...I already knew about the window.close and looked at the MDN documentation that is why I came here.

Comment: torazaburo...I was just trying different things I'm not an expert in javascript at all...nice to know though!

Comment: -3 and not solved.....jesus

Answer (score -1, accepted):

below script will only work in Firefox.if we enable the settings allow_scripts_to_close_windows.

For that

1.Open FireFox

2.Enter `about:config` in Address bar

3.It will open a Config page of Firefox

4.Search `allow_scripts_to_close_windows`

5.It will show `allow_scripts_to_close_windows`.by default value will be false.To enable double click on the `allow_scripts_to_close_windows` row.It will change to true

6.Close Firefox

Then execute the below script.

```
<script>
var basket = prompt("are you a basket case (yes/no) ?");


if (basket === "yes")
{
    window.close()
}
var vegtables = prompt("How many times do you eat vegtables at least once a day in a week ?");
if (parseInt(vegtables) >= 6) {
    alert("Good job! keep it up!")   
}
else {
    alert("You need to eat more vegtables, visit my health and reboot pages!")
}

</script>
```

Comment: it didn't work it just went on to the next question..

Comment: it will close current tab only.try now i have updated the code.also make sure that yes is typed correctly

Comment: that worked or not,marcus ?

Comment: I used your code it still asks the question after you answer yes

Comment: do I need a break; in there????

Comment: it is working fine here.which browser u r using IE ?

Comment: working fine in chrome.not work in firefox

Comment: is there a reason why it would stay open if I have other tabs open?

Comment: Why would It still ask the second question after you already answer yes to the first one?

Comment: First you need to enable the settings allow_scripts_to_close_windows in firefox to work the above script

Comment: so it is a browser problem not a code problem?

Comment: yes.updated the answer.did it work.thanks to Mr.Erez

Answer (score -2):

```
window.close();
```

instead of

```
window.closeCurrentWindow();
```

and because you said in a comment you are using firefox,
 you can change settings, go to url `about:config`,

change to this value-

```
dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows = true
```

Comment: any answer has yet to work

Comment: where do I put that at?

Comment: Neither `window.closeCurrentWindow` nor `window.close` will work if it's hiding inside a function.